# mySQL SELECT help. IF or EXISTS?

Tags: mysql

I have this DB structure

```
* user
user_id
name

* client
client_id
name

* user_client
user_client_id
user_id
client_id

* message
message_id
client_id
description
```

If there are entries on `user_client` then the user has permissions restricted to the specific clients listed for his id on the table. If there are no entries, then the user has access to any client.

How can I select only messages that the user can read?

I'm trying to do an IF on the WHERE clause to check if any entries on the `user_client` table but I don't know where to go from there. It needs to select all messages from any client if no entries on `user_client` or only messages for `client_id` specified on `user_client` table

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you show your query you are trying to fix?

Comment: are you here? wouold you answer my question please? and show expected result?

Comment: Hi Alex! Just saw your message. I didn't finish the query, cause I realized is was going on the wrong direction and I was missing something. But this was what I had:
SELECT
   message.message_id,
   message.description
  FROM
   message
  WHERE
   discussionMessage.insertWhen >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
   AND 
   IF ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM user_client WHERE user_id = user.user_id) >= 1
   
   message.clientId IN (
    SELECT
     client_id
    FROM
     user_client
    WHERE
     user_client.userId = {USERIDHERE}
   ),  , )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing two different queries: one for the *superusers* and the other for the restricted users. Then you can join the two results with a UNION.

```
    SELECT M.message_id,
           M.client_id,
           M.description
      FROM message M
INNER JOIN user_client UC ON (UC.client_id = M.client_id)
INNER JOIN user U ON (UC.user_id = U.id)
     WHERE U.id = :user_id

     UNION

    SELECT M.message_id,
           M.client_id,
           M.description
      FROM message M
     WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
               SELECT *
                 FROM user_client
                WHERE user_id = :user_id
           )
```

You can obtain the same result with other queries but IMHO this one is clearer and more maintainable.

Edit: If you want to ensure that the user exists you should join the second query with the user table.

```
    SELECT M.message_id,
           M.client_id,
           M.description
      FROM message M
      JOIN user U
     WHERE U.id = :user_id
       AND NOT EXISTS ( 
               SELECT *
                 FROM user_client
                WHERE user_id = :user_id
           )
```

Comment: Hi Jordi! I was able to use your query to make it work on my side! Thanks, I'm still finishing and will mark as accepted as answer as soon as I do all tests.

Comment: Thank you. Just keep keep in mind that if you pass an unexistent :user_id it will return all the messages. You can either make sure that the user exists before you call the query or modify the second part of the union to check that the user exists.

Comment: Hi @jordi-llull it worked, I just saw the message you sent about returning all messages if user doesn't exists, should I verify that with a mysql query and if the number of rows returned is bigger than zero it will call the message query or how do you mean on your message, is it possible to add to the query?

Comment: I just edited the answer to add a version of the second query that actually checks that the user exists. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One way the do this could be to use two different queries to create a set of the messages users can see and filter according to your needs; something like this should work:

```
select * from (
    select u.user_id, u.name, c.name client, m.message_id, m.description 
    from user u
    join user_client uc on u.user_id = uc.user_id
    join client c on uc.client_id = c.client_id
    join message m on c.client_id = m.client_id
    union all
    select u.user_id, u.name, c.name client, m.message_id, m.description
    from user u
    cross join client c 
    join message m on c.client_id = m.client_id
    where user_id not in (select user_id from user_client)
) x
where x.user_id = 1;
```

Here users present in the user_client table are restricted to the set of messages that they have access to (the first set in the union), while users not present in the user_client table can see all messages (the second set in the union).

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5b22e/2)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, such as

1) Administrative user... They can look at EVERYTHING since they would have no records in the user_client table.

2) Client Supervisor... Such a person who's primary responsibility is to a specific client (or multiple clients).  Therefore, the user DOES have a record in the user_client table.  If so, then only allow the user to see records for those clients they DO have associations with.

```
select
      m.message_id,
      m.client_id,
      m.description,
      c.name as clientName
   from
      ( select count(*) as HasClients
           from user_client
           where user_id = TheUserYouWant ) ClientCheck,
      message m
         left join user_client uc
            on m.client_id = uc.client_id
           AND uc.user_id = TheUserYouWant
         join client c
            on m.client_id = c.client_id
   where
         ClientCheck.HasClients = 0
      OR NOT uc.user_id IS NULL
```

The query looks at the user_client table TWICE.  The first time is to just get a count of those records that DO exist for the given user, regardless of which client associated with.  The query will always come back with 1 row and it will either be 0 (no such records), or greater than 1 (however many they are associated with).

The second instance is a LEFT-JOIN to the user_client table, JUST IN CASE the person IS restricted to only looking at their own client messages.

The WHERE clause now comes in and says... if the underlying count of clients was zero, then ok to give me all messages.  If any other value, then the user ID in the user_client table (as left-joined to the messages on both the CLIENT AND THE USER you want) MUST EXIST (via NOT a NULL value for the user_id column).

Now, you probably don't want to query EVERY message as it could get quite large as your database grows, but you could put whatever other criteria in the WHERE clause, such as date restrictions and/or client(s) you are interested in.