# Followup: mySQL SELECT help. IF or EXISTS?

Tags: mysql

I was helped on this question [mySQL SELECT help. IF or EXISTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678898/mysql-select-help-if-or-exists) before and now I have a follow up question regarding that. Here it is the table structure again:

```
<code>
* user
user_id
name

* client
client_id
name

* user_client
user_client_id
user_id
client_id
</code>
```

Now I don't want to join with any other table, I just want to pull the permissions, the results set should return the clients allowed by the user or all of the clients ids if the user exists and if there's no entry for that user on user_client. Meaning that if there's no rows for a user_id on user_client he can access all clients.

I couldn't figure it out how to make it work without a table to join like I had on the previous question (in that case message)

Thank you guys!

EDIT:
Ok, trying to explain better:
Let's say on tables I have

```
<code>
user_id 
1
2
3

client_id
10
11
12
13
14

On user_client table
user_id    client_id
1          11
1          13
3          14
3          10
</code>
```

I want the results to be:
If user_id is 1 it will have a results set containing 11 and 13. 
If user_id is 3 it will have a results set containing 14, 10.
If user_id is 2 it will have a results set containing 10, 11, 12, 13 and 14.

I hope I explained better.

Comment: @jordi-llull could you help me with this one? Thanks!

Comment: So you want to select all `client_id` from a `particular user_id`?

Comment: 1) You can't shout out for a specific user to answer like that; even if it wasn't inappropriate, it doesn't work unless the user has answered or commented to this question. 2) You haven't clearly explained what you're trying to do. Post some sample data and the results you'd like to obtain from that data, along with what you've tried so far that isn't working for you. (You mention "pemissions", but there's no *permissions* in any of the table definitions you've posted, meaning we couldn't answer if we wanted to because the information isn't there.)

Comment: Hi @KenWhite thanks for the shout explanation, I didn't know that. I edit my question to explain better. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give more details in your question so people really understand what you want.

Anyway, the query is pretty straight forward. Just take the query from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678898/mysql-select-help-if-or-exists/28680574#28680574) and remove the unnecessary joins.

```
 SELECT client_id
   FROM user_client
  WHERE user_id = :user_id

 UNION

 SELECT client_id
   FROM client
   JOIN `user` U
  WHERE U.id = :user_id
    AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
              FROM user_client
             WHERE user_id = U.id
      )
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I appreciate your help. The only thing that is doing wrong is that it's not showing all client_id only the ones that are on the user_client table while it should show all the  client_id on the client table in case it doesn't exists user_id on the user_client

Comment: You are right! I edited the answer and fixed the second part of the union. Not it selects from client instead of user_client.